# How to use winfo_children to modify the tkinter buttons gridded in different frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I got  a list of all the buttons and the frames where they extend from using this code:

```
def childrens (window) :
    lst = window.winfo_children()

    for item in lst :
        if item.winfo_children() :
            _list.extend(item.winfo_children())

    print (_list)
```

which gives me this:

```
[<tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe>, <tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe2>,
 <tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe3>, <tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe4>,
 <tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe5>, <tkinter.LabelFrame object .!labelframe6>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe.!button>, <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe.!button2>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe.!button3>, <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe.!button4>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe2.!button>, <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe2.!button2>,
 <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe2.!button3>, <tkinter.Button object .!labelframe2.!button4>]
```

Now how do I really get to use this to modify the buttons that I implemented?

Comment: Group up all the buttons by looping through the `_list` and then use `isinstance` to check if the current item is an object of `Button` then append to a `btn_lst` and then access each item from the list and do something with it or edit it: `btn_lst[1].config(state='disabled')`

Comment: Your code doesn't work as posted. You haven't initialized _list, and your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley i copied the code and changed the variables to suit me haphazardly, thank you for spotting it.

Answer (score 2):

The items in the list are widgets. You can directly iterate over them and do whatever you want.

There are bugs in the code you posted, but assuming those bugs were fixed you could directly iterate over the contents of `_list` or `list` (it's not clear what you intended). You can use [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) to determine if the widget is a button.

```
for widget in _list:
    if isinstance(widget, tk.Button):
        widget.configure(...)
```